# React Native IOS Block Photo Library Access

Tags: ios, react-native

I have been researching this for serval days and have not found the answer. Is there a way to block access to Photo Library on IOS. I have an app that contains a web view and in that web view there is an option to upload a photo. I would like that option to not appear and only appear the take photo option (In this image take photo does not show because it was taken from my simulator).

[image]

Comment: webview? if you use input for upload you should check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy package for the same called react-native-image-picker.
It allows you both to take a photo and access library unless the user does not grant access.